# Making a new line in A-frame from JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, aframe

I have done an A-frame 360 view. I am pulling data from a JSON file called `seat_perlis.json`. And now I want to make a series of panels within the scene. Below is my jQuery code.

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent ('jsonreader',
{

init: function()
{
var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
var el = document.createElement('a-text');


$.getJSON( "seat_perlis.json", function( response ) {

     console.log(response);

  //push data to items

    $.each( response.data, function( key, val ) {
      $('#jadah').append(`\
        <a-entity layout="type: box; margin: 1.6" scale="0.8 0.8" position="0 -1 -4">\
       <a-text value='${val.name} \n ${val.code_name} \n ${val.candidate_seats[0].candidate.name}' color="red" id="entity1-1"></a-text>\

        </a-entity>\
        `);

   });//end each

 }); //end getJSON

}
});
```

and below is an example of the JSON file

```
{
"data": [
  {
        "id": 1,
        "state_id": 1,
        "name": "Titi Tinggi",
        "code_name": "N1",
        "type": "DUN",
        "hot_seat": true,
        "election_year": 2013,
        "registered_voters": 9159,
        "spoilt": 0,
        "turnout": 7332,
        "turnout_percent": 80,
        "majority": 1486,
        "majority_percent": 20,
        "race_malay": 6734,
        "race_chinese": 2128,
        "race_india": 258,
        "race_bumi": null,
        "race_nonbumi": null,
        "race_others": 54,
        "state": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Perlis",
            "code": "PER"
        },
        "candidate_seats": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "candidate_id": 2538,
                "seat_id": 1,
                "party_id": 1,
                "verified_vote": 3925,
                "unverified_vote": null,
                "status": "WON",
                "candidate": {
                    "id": 2538,
                    "name": "Khaw Hock Kong",
                    "image": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "candidate_id": 2540,
                "seat_id": 1,
                "party_id": 100,
                "verified_vote": 968,
                "unverified_vote": null,
                "status": null,
                "candidate": {
                    "id": 2540,
                    "name": "Yaacob Bin Man",
                    "image": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "candidate_id": 2539,
                "seat_id": 1,
                "party_id": 300,
                "verified_vote": 2439,
                "unverified_vote": null,
                "status": "",
                "candidate": {
                    "id": 2539,
                    "name": "Teh Seng Chuan",
                    "image": null
```

Linked is the intended result ->
[Image][1]

Now the JSON data is in but it went straight up. I dont know how to break it.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is and what you intend to happen?

Comment: problem is that I cant break the JSON data into a new position so that it would make a row of columns in A-frame. This is what I intend to make and also the state that the a-frame is in is something like this -> https://imgur.com/a/l0KbW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new layout-entity for each entry in your json data, i.e. you create this:

```
<a-entity layout="type: box; margin: 1.6" scale="0.8 0.8" position="0 -1 -4">
   <a-text value="... entry 1 ..."></a-text>
</a-entity>
<a-entity layout="type: box; margin: 1.6" scale="0.8 0.8" position="0 -1 -4">
   <a-text value="... entry 2 ..."></a-text>
</a-entity>
<a-entity layout="type: box; margin: 1.6" scale="0.8 0.8" position="0 -1 -4">
   <a-text value="... entry 3 ..."></a-text>
</a-entity>
```

You want (if I understand you correctly) something like this without always generating a new layout entity:

```
<a-entity layout="type: box; margin: 1.6" scale="0.8 0.8" position="0 -1 -4">
   <a-text value="... entry 1 ..."></a-text>
   <a-text value="... entry 2 ..."></a-text>
   <a-text value="... entry 3 ..."></a-text>
</a-entity>
```

So you should apped all the `a-text` nodes to the same `a-entity`, not to `#jadah`.

On a side note, you give all the `a-text` elements the same ID!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you kind stranger!